# XQuery Show Collection Name

Tags: xquery, marklogic

What is the XQuery to search the entire database and show the collection name which has a given element-name?

Comment: "collection name which has a given element-name"...Are you asking for how to query all names of elements belonging to a given collection?

Comment: no, query to search through all the element names in the database and show only the collection names that contain the matching element-name in the database

Comment: So for every element name in the database, you want to return the name of any collection that element belongs to?

Comment: At this point, please give an example document and collection names to further articulate the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

You can find out which collections contain documents matching a query with a `cts:collections()` lexicon lookup.  You can use a `cts:element-query()` with a `cts:true-query()` to match an element on name regardless of content.

Putting those two ingredients together, the query would look something like:

```
cts:collections((), (),
    cts:element-query(QName("namespace", "name"), cts:true-query())
    )
```

The collection lexicon must be enabled for the database, which is the default in MarkLogic 9.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I just ran the following query and got no response, why? My collection lexicon is enabled by the way:

cts:collections((), (), cts:element-query(QName("http://www.w3.org/1999/html", "adr_key"), cts:true-query()))

Comment: My guess would be that you have the wrong namespace, or you don't have a document that matches.

Comment: FWIW, my guess is the same as Harry's.

Comment: It's got to be the wrong namespace. "http://www.w3.org/1999/html" is the namespace for html elements; adr_key is not an HTML element.

Answer (score 0):

Run it this way- I think it does what you expect. Returns the collections that include the "adr_key" element. Your query didn't work because your data is in the default namespace, not the html namespace that you have in your example. That semicolon can't be good either...anyway, here you go-

```
cts:collections((), (),
cts:element-query(QName("", "adr_key"), cts:true-query())
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your response. But I just ran the following query and got no response, why? My collection lexicon is enabled by the way:

cts:collections((), (), 
cts:element-query(QName("http://www.w3.org/1999/html", "adr_key"), cts:true-query()))

Comment: this should be a comment on ehennum's answer, rather than being posted as an answer. That said, no results suggests that you don't have any matching documents. If that doesn't seem right, please post a sample doc.